# Render a set of points with colors

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to render a set of points with colors in unity and I have followed this example http://www.kamend.com/2014/05/rendering-a-point-cloud-inside-unity/ to generate points and their colors randomly.

C# code

```
public class PointCloud : MonoBehaviour 
{ 
  private Mesh mesh;
  int numPoints = 60000;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
    mesh = new Mesh();

    GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
    CreateMesh();
  }

  void CreateMesh() {
    Vector3[] points = new Vector3[numPoints];
    int[] indecies = new int[numPoints];
    Color[] colors = new Color[numPoints];
    for(int i=0;i<points.Length;++i) {
        points[i] = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10,10), Random.Range (-10,10), Random.Range (-10,10));
        indecies[i] = i;
        colors[i] = new Color(Random.Range(0.0f,1.0f),Random.Range (0.0f,1.0f),Random.Range(0.0f,1.0f),1.0f);
    }

    mesh.vertices = points;
    mesh.colors = colors;
    mesh.SetIndices(indecies, MeshTopology.Points,0);

  }
}
```

Shader

```
Shader "Custom/VertexColor" {
    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            LOD 200

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            struct VertexInput 
            {
                float4 v : POSITION;
                float4 color: COLOR;
            };

            struct VertexOutput 
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float4 col : COLOR;
            };

            VertexOutput vert(VertexInput v) 
            {
                VertexOutput o;
                o.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.v);
                o.col = v.color;

                return o;
            }

            float4 frag(VertexOutput o) : COLOR
            {
                return o.col;
            }

            ENDCG
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to change colors of these points? Since I set colors of these points with a constant values but it does not work.

Comment: I would recommend you to define struct/class that contains point member as Vector3 type, index member as int type and color member as Color type, call this struct/class whatever name you want and create one array of this struct/class with length = numPoints, instead of creating three arrays with length = numPoints: points, indecies and colors. This makes the code easier to use, to read and also improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something wrong with the unity. I build many times and restart unity then it works perfectly.